# Excel 2011 for Mac - formula property dropdown list missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

Basically missing the dropdown properties list on Excel 2011 for Mac. How do I enable/show it?

[image]

I've already:

- ticked the "show function ScreenTips option" under `Excel Preferences > View > Window options`. There's no "Advanced" category in the Preference pane. Can I enable Advanced preference too?
- clicked the `,[range_lookup])` argument in the `vlookup()` formula, with a combination of + cmd, + shift, + alt, + ctrl. No dropdown lists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly what you asked, but maybe a viable alternative...

Did you try the Formula Builder?
View Menu > Toolbox >
(It will also offer the option if you get a function 'wrong'.)

It really save the effort of getting all the syntax right.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I resorted to Formula Builder instead. Although it would be more convenient to have a dropdown list autocomplete feature on Macs.